# Apache redirect all https (443) request to external server

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian-based

I want to redirect all https requests (443) to another server, how can I do this in apache?

What I want to do is:

All https requests on https://server1.com redirect to https://server2.com

Anyone knows how I can achieve this? An example would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks testing your suggestions! :)

Comment: I think you can get iptables to do that if you have root access

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^server1.ca$
RewriteRule (.*) https://server2.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If HTTPS, redirect everything to your new site coming from server1.com

Answer (score 0):

You will need certificates in both servers, then you can redirect using .htaccess (if you're using apache) or web.config (if you're using IIS).

Example of .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^server2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://server2.com/$1 [L]
```

If you're using IIS let me know, i can get you a sample web.config :)